# Xamarin Installion: System.MissingMethodException error

Tags: xamarin

I am getting the below error while installing Xamarin:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: xamarininstaller.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 3.6.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 561d8cdc
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 4ba1da6f
  Problem Signature 07: 16ff
  Problem Signature 08: e
  Problem Signature 09: System.MissingMethodException
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Stack overflow is for programming questions. Please contact xamarin for these kind of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Installation issues like this are best handled directly by us (Xamarin Support) rather than posting here - StackOverflow is primarily for programming / code questions.

We would normally recommend trying a manual installation to start off with (installing each package separately).

Please reach out to contact@xamarin.com for assistance with this (please add the link to this question in your email) and we can send you the manual installation download links.